# What is the AdoptOpenJDK policy for rebuilding offical docker Images?

Tags: java, docker, dockerhub, adoptopenjdk

I am using the AdoptOpenJDK 11 official docker image from https://hub.docker.com/_/adoptopenjdk my container registry is reporting that the underlying Ubuntu 18.04 image has known vulnerabilities, which appear to be fixed in later versions of the Ubuntu image than the one that the official AdoptOpenJDK 11 image is based on.

Does the AdoptOpenJDK make new releases of the docker image whenever the underlying Ubuntu base image is updated or only when there is a new release of the JDK?

Comment: do not use blackbox images. Request from them to show you their dockerfile

Comment: AdoptOpenJDK dockerfiles are all on GithHub I have read through them they are fine. My issue is understanding thier policy to see if they monitor the Ubuntu base images and rebuild when it has new security fixes ... etc.